# windows batch compare md5sum with md5 file contents

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server

I have a folder with a few zip files called 1.zip, 2.zip and so on.

The folder also has md5 files for each zip like this 1.zip.md5 ... n.zip.md5

md5 files have the md5sum in uppercase with a new line at the end

I am trying to write a batch program that will read all zip files, compute the md5sum of them and compare it to the one in the associated md5 file.

I have gotten this far.

```
@echo off
set mypath=G:\Temp\

for %%f in (*.zip) do (
  echo PROCESSING: %mypath%%%f
  md5sum < %mypath%%%f > %mypath%%%f.tmp
  set /p sum=<%mypath%%%f.tmp
  echo SUM: %sum%
  :rm %mypath%%%f.tmp
  pause
)
pause
```

My problem is that `set /p sum=<%mypath%%%f.tmp` does not seem to get the contents for some reason.

On top of that md5sum outputs lowercase md5sum and followed by `*-`.

I am new in batch and already spent too many hours trying to figure this out.

Can someone give me some tips on what am I doing wrong and how I might be able to do some debugging when I get stuck again?

After I get over this I will need to split the tpm file contents by space to separate the md5sum and uppercase it. Hope that will be easy them compare should be even easier.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set mypath=.
rem cd /d "%mypath%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.zip) do (
  echo PROCESSING: %%~dpfnxf
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=*- " %%S in ('md5sum ^< "%%~dpfnxf" ') do set "sum=%%S" 
  echo SUM: !sum!
  :rm %mypath%%%f.tmp
  pause
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: what is the output of `md5sum < "%mypath%%%f` with random picked zip file?

Comment: 9930a67db849bbbf483d72a3fc92d88a *-

Comment: did you entered the `mypath=G:\Temp\` because there's no `cd` or `pushd` in your script..?(Now I'm testing the script by myself)

Comment: That is the path where the files are located. The script is the one I posted. Nothing else in it. Server is Windows Azure 2012.

Comment: i think there was a changes in the how `set /p` works in win 2012.E.g. printing of string without new line does not work anymore : `echo|set /=print this on same line`

Comment: Thank you. Got any hints about trimming ` *-` from the sum and comparing it uppercase to the md5 file?

Comment: updated the answer.More info you can find here : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php